# Custom colour for matlab surface plot

Tags: matlab, dictionary, colors, command, contour

I have loaded in some topographic data to matlab, and created surf, surfl and contour plots of this data, colouring them using colormap. The topographic data ranges from 0 to 2500 m.

I want to plot a map that colours any topography below 200 m blue, above 500 m red, and between 200 and 500 m green. Is it possible to do this? Could anyone give me any tips regarding the command required to do so?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

You may play with `colormap` and the fourth input of `surf`.

The following plot

[image]

is produced by

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(1000);

%colormap
cmap = [0.6 0.2 0.4; 
        0.5 0.5 0.5; 
        0.1 0.9 0.9];  

Zcolor = zeros(size(Z));                   
threshold = 2;
Zcolor(Z <= -threshold)                 = 1;  % first row of cmap
Zcolor(Z > -threshold & Z < threshold)  = 2;  % second row of cmap
Zcolor(Z >= threshold)                  = 3;  % third row of cmap

figure('Color','w');
surf(X, Y, Z, Zcolor, 'EdgeColor', 'None');
colormap(cmap); 
light('Position', [0 -2 1])
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! it is very helpful. However, when I modify the code so it works for my data, the 

Zcolor(Z <= -threshold)                 = 1;

doesn't work properly. As in, it isn't using the color defined in the first row of cmap, it is using a different line. This happens with all three of the 'Zcolor' rows

Comment: MATLAB performs a linear transformation on this data to obtain colors from the current colormap. Typically, the lowest Zcolor value will be assigned the minimum of the colormap and the highest Zcolor the maximum. Everything in between these two values will be scaled.

Answer (score 2):

```
hsurf=surf(...)
set(hsurf,'FaceColor','interp')
```

`doc surf` for more information.

Comment: This hasn't made the plot look any different. Could you tell me how I would use this to set each height to a colour?